# SharePoint 3.0 service account

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008, sharepoint

We have a SharePoint 3 site that is currently configured to run under a admin account.  I have been tasked with reconfiguring it to run under a service account.  Unfortunately, when I update the application pools in IIS to run under a new account, when I attempt to browse to the site I receive this message: "Cannot connect to the configuration database."  I gave the new service account all the same permissions as the admin account in SQL, and even tried using the SQL service account, which results in the same message.  I'm not sure the issue is with SQL.  What else am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/934838

Comment: also this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263445(office.12).aspx